# Flex mobile tabBar adjust width?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder, flex4.5

How to change the tabBar height size?

[image]

is it possible to apply for all my views. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                                  initialize="tabbedviewnavigatorapplication1_initializeHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function tabbedviewnavigatorapplication1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.tabbedNavigator.tabBar.height = 15;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Home" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.HomeView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Page" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.PageView"/>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>
```

I hope you mean really the height and not the width for each tab-item.

Frank

Answer (score 0):

Use [tabBar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ButtonBar.html).[height](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#height)?

```
tabBar.height = newValue
```

Or was there more to your question?

Comment: do i need to import any statement? i can't put it in anyway, as FB don't have tabBar. the only place to put it is in: 
 <fx:Declarations>
  <s:TabBar height="5"/>
 </fx:Declarations>

but is it not working and it said not mobile - optimized.

Comment: @jameslcs Your question was about changing the height of the tabBar.  You won't be able to do that if you don't have an instance of the tabBar created somehow.  Did you mean to ask a different question, such as how to resize the Flex Mobile ActionBar?  Or how to resize the tabs of a TabbedNavigatorApplication?

Comment: sorry for not making it clear, I have edited my question please refer above. I would to know how to resize the mobile tabBar? thank